# Change DatePicker Language Yii2

Tags: datepicker, yii2, bootstrap-4

How can I change the default language (English) of the [DatePicker](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker) in Yii2?

**Sample Code:**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'birthday')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter birth date ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        'autoclose'=>true
    ]
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding the language field like:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'birthday')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
    'language' => 'it',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter birth date ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        'autoclose'=>true
    ]
]); ?>
```

Truncated code:

```
'language' => 'it'
```

*Here for example I changed the language to* `Italian`.